# Get the column number in Ultragrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have to get the column number in the grid.

Eg: If i have `Name`,`Age`,`Number` as three columns in the grid and i give the `headertext`(Age) of the column it should return the `Number`(2) which represents the `Age` is 2nd column of the grid.

```
For Each UltraGridColumn In Me.TransactionsGrid.Rows.Band.Columns
    If (UltraGridColumn.Hidden = False) Then
        'UltraGridColumn.Header.Caption
        'Get the cell
         UltraGridCell = UltraGridRow.Cells("Number Here")
    End If
Next
```

Now here i have to get the column number which is not `hidden`. I have the `headertext` of the column and i need the number.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every UltraGridColumn has a property called Index that is the index of the column in the band's column collection. So if you want to search a column using the header text you could write this

```
For Each col In Me.TransactionsGrid.Rows.Band.Columns
     If (col.Hidden = False) Then
         if col.Header.Caption = searchedHeaderText Then
              grid.ActiveRow.Cells(col).Value = col.Index.ToString()
         End If
     End If
Next
```

What do you really want to do with the Index information is not very clear from your questio, so I have used this info to set the value of the ActiveRow in the cell corrisponding to the column searched. Add more info to your question is this is not what you want.

Comment: With the help of the index i'm trying to find the cell have to set an image inside that.

Comment: can u help me in this ques @Steve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583718/remove-image-in-a-cell-of-ultragrid