# Remove image in a cell of Ultragrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have set image to a cell and i have to remove at some point of time.

//Code

```
                   'Get the first cell of the first column in the grid
                    UltraGridCell = UltraGridRow.Cells(UltraGridColumn.Index)

                   If (UltraGridColumn.Hidden = False) Then

                        'Set the cell image
                        UltraGridCell.Appearance.Image = My.Resources.Tran_comment_161
                        UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageHAlign = HAlign.Right
                        UltraGridCell.Appearance.ImageVAlign = VAlign.Top

                        Exit For
                  Else

                   'Code to remove the image from the cell

                  End If
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with

```
cell.Appearance.ResetImage()
```

Practically there is a `ResetXXXX` method for every `Appearance` property of the cell, or you could Reset everything to the default values calling the general method

```
cell.Appearance.Reset()
```

Comment: Note that you should dispose the image that was retrieved from My.Resources.Tran_comment_161 when you are done with it.  This will not happen automatically and the grid will not dispose it as the grid doesn't know if you have other references to the image.